# eclipse rcp palette creation

Tags: eclipse-rcp, widget, palette

Does any one know how to create a palette like Visual Editor widget palette?

I think that it should be e component but I don't know where to find it and how to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by looking at the [sources](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/downloads/?showAll=1&hlbuild=R200909301124&project=ve#R200909301124) of the [Eclipse **Visual Editor** project](https://web.archive.org/web/20110606051628/http://www.eclipse.org:80/vep/);.
They did implement a [similar feature](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/).

[image]
<sub>(source: [ibm.com](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecvisual/VisEdit.gif))</sub>

Comment: I would have like to avoid this, but after some research on internet I also reached to the same conclusion. Thanks